# How do I detect if AsymmetricAlgorithm is a private key or a public key

Tags: c#, cryptography, private-key, public-key

Is there a simple way to check if a given AsymmetricAlgorithm is a private or a public key? Consider the following example:

```
private void SavePrivateKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm asymmetricAlgorithm)
{
    // if (asymmetricAlgorithm.IsPrivateKey == false)
    //     throw new ArgumentException();
}

private void SavePrivateKeys()
{
    var certificate = CreateCertificate();
    var privateKey = RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(certificate);
    var publicKey = RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPublicKey(certificate);
    SavePrivateKey(privateKey);
    SavePrivateKey(publicKey); // this should throw an exception
}

private X509Certificate2 CreateCertificate()
{
    CngKeyCreationParameters keyParams = new CngKeyCreationParameters();
    keyParams.KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.Signing;
    keyParams.Provider = CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider;
    keyParams.ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowExport | CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport;
    keyParams.Parameters.Add(new CngProperty("Length", BitConverter.GetBytes(2048), CngPropertyOptions.None));
    var cngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), keyParams);
    var rsaKey = new RSACng(cngKey);
    var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=mycert", rsaKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
    var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));
    return cert;
}
```

Here, both private and public keys have the same type - RSACng. In theory I can try to export key parameters and see if the public key fails to export the private key params. But then I would not know if the export failed because it is a public key, or because it is missing export policies or something else went wrong. Also the underlying key type may be different, it could be RSACng, RSACryptoServiceProvider, DSA etc.

Comment: The whole structure of Mickeysofts API confuses public and private keys and even certificates and private keys. Why? I guess that's just the way they designed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToXmlString()` method takes in the `includePrivateParameters` parameter. If that parameter is set, and the `AsymmetricAlgorithm` object does not include information about the private key, `ToXmlString()` will throw a `CryptographicException` exception:

```
private void SavePrivateKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm aa)
{
    System.Console.Write("This is ");
    try
    {
        aa.ToXmlString(true);
    }
    catch(CryptographicException ce)
    {
        System.Console.Write("not ");
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("a private key");
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the export parameters approach that I was mentioning. If, for example, the export policies are missing plain text export policy, the exception will be the same even for private keys.

Comment: Ah, in that case you may be stuck having to convert the key to a derived type. Don't think there is much else you can do with `AsymmetricAlgorithm`.